# How can I find the path in which a file is open

Tags: windows, dfs, file-server

I need to migrate a Server 2008 Fileserver. My problem is, that some Users have access to there data over DFS and other have mapped simple Shares. Now I have migrated the DFS but I don't know which users have manual mapped shares whitout DFS. Is there any way to find it out? In Computermanagement I can only see the local path.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to find out which user uses which type of "shortcut" connection. The fileserver just sees files (and requests for them) - regardless if the request came through a UNC path, a mapped drive, a SMB-URI or a self-written smbclient. There is no difference in using (for example) saved links on the desktop, going through remote folder trees or using a shortcut (like mapped drives).

But if you are using DFS, there is an AD in which you can always use GPOs to map drives to paths. Which is what almost 99,99% of all business networks do.